# Minimise keyboard while going android app to background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard, window-soft-input-mode

When app goes to background then keyboard should be minimise instead of hide. I also tried to get Menu device button click listener but it is also not able to get.

Comment: what do you mean by minimize and but not hide? when app goes to background, keyboard should not be visible at that moment. Also show us what you have done so far.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the minimized keyboard and closed keyboard?